# interpolate values and replace empty cells with NA

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, time-series, interpolation

I would like to linearly interpolate time series data (in steps of 60 seconds in a data frame as follows, where `seconds` is the variable to be interpolated:

`mydf <- data.frame(measurement = c(2,6,4,1,7), other_measurement = c(2,5,8,6,4), seconds = c(60,60,120,360,360))`

(The actual data frame is many magnitudes larger than this.)

Then, once those intermediary multiples of 60 are interpolated, I would like to fill in the cells that are generated with NA. I found some solutions that are close to this, like creating a data frame of multiples of 60 and merging it with my data frame, but none that worked exactly and still filled in all of the missing cells across multiple columns. Thank you!

Comment: "interpolate" and "fill in the cells that are generated with "NA" are mutually exclusive. Please provide your expected output given this sample data.

Comment: I want to interpolate the seconds variable so, c(60,60,120,180,240,300,360,360). This will necessarily require generating more rows in the data frame, which I would like to fill with NA, so measurement = c(2,5,8,NA,NA,NA,6,4)

Comment: are the existing values of `seconds` always aligned with 60? That is, is it safe to assume that `all(mydf$seconds %% 60 == 0)`? (It is here, just want to make it is in the design of the data as well.)

Comment: Yes, always multiples of 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### base R

```r
newdf <- data.frame(seconds = do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(mydf$seconds)), by = 60)))
merge(mydf, newdf, all = TRUE)
#   seconds measurement other_measurement
# 1      60           2                 2
# 2      60           6                 5
# 3     120           4                 8
# 4     180          NA                NA
# 5     240          NA                NA
# 6     300          NA                NA
# 7     360           1                 6
# 8     360           7                 4
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  summarize(seconds = seq(min(seconds), max(seconds), by = 60)) %>%
  full_join(mydf, ., by = "seconds")
#   measurement other_measurement seconds
# 1           2                 2      60
# 2           6                 5      60
# 3           4                 8     120
# 4           1                 6     360
# 5           7                 4     360
# 6          NA                NA     180
# 7          NA                NA     240
# 8          NA                NA     300
```

Comment: Thank you! That did work. And if there is one column with consistent values, is there a way to edit the code so that those values are simply repeated instead of replaced with NA like in `measurement` and `other_measurement`?

Comment: Do you mean like `%>% fill(measurement, other_measurement)`? (Base R: `mydf$measurement <- zoo::na.locf(mydf$measurement, partial = FALSE)`, same for the other.)

Comment: Do either of those work?